# Primefaces columnGroup not working with ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to dynamically generate headers with `ui:repeat` and `p:columnGroup`, but it is not working.

```
<p:columnGroup type="header">       
    <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.featureList}" var="feature">
      <p:row>
         <p:column headerText="#{feature}" />
         <ui:repeat value="#{testBean.models}" var="model" >
            <p:column headerText="#{model.features.get(feature)}" />
         </ui:repeat>
     </p:row>  
    </ui:repeat>
</p:columnGroup>
```

`testBean.featureList` and `testBean.models` are just arrayLists, and `model.features` is a `Map<String, String>`.

I've looked around primefaces forum and found some related threads:

- http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16606&hilit=datatable+header
- http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=28659
- http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29887

Hope somebody could help this out. Thanks!

Comment: What Implementation and Which version of JSF you are using?

Comment: Primefaces builds its table model before `ui:repeat` acts, so it's impossible for that to work. You can give a try to `c:forEach` instead, or bind your `dataTable` to a managed bean property and build it in the managed bean before page being rendered.

Comment: @KishorP I'm using Primefaces 4.0 and Apache Myfaces 2.1

Comment: @XtremeBiker Thanks! But the problem with `c:forEach` is that it renders before `f:preRenderView`, then I could not use data generated with query parameter in `c:forEach`. Any thoughts on this issue?